# Retrieve xml of all packages on a server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

Is it possible to retrieve the XML of all SSIS packages on a server?
DTSX files are xml files. 
I want to retrieve the raw xml of all packages on a server (those deployed in the catalog as well as those deployed in the msdb).

In SSRS this is very simple, just `SELECT CONVERT(varbinary(max),Content) AS Content from  dbo.catalog.content` but is something like this possible in SSIS?

edit: I know how to read dtsx from file. I need to find the xml of packages deployed to msdb or catalog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible as long as you know the location of the SSIS (.dtsx) packages. When they're stored as .dtsx files you would use OPENROWSET, OPENXML or something similar to import the XML file. To get all files you would use a t-SQL loop for each file you want to query. Here's a link with examples: [Using XML Data Type Methods to query SSIS Packages](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/peter_debetta/archive/2006/07/13/Using-XML-Data-Type-Methods-to-query-SSIS-Packages.aspx)

Querying SSIS packages deployed to the msdb or SSIS package store is a little easier provided you have a basic understanding XML data type methods. Here's a link that describes how you would query packages in the MSDB: [List all SSIS packages stored in msdb database](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/List-all-SSIS-packages-3b247394)

Comment: Sorry, I clarified my question. I know how to read dtsx from file. I need to find the xml of packages deployed to msdb or catalog.